# Are these string in concat command created in string pool?

Tags: java, string

Assume I write something like this in Java:

```
String a = args[0]; // user input from keyboard
String b = a + "foo1";
String c = "foo2" + "foo3";
```

Will "foo1", "foo2", "foo3"  be created in String pool?

Comment: Why do you care? This is trivia that is really not relevant for day-to-day programming in Java.

Comment: Note: `"foo2" + "foo3"` does not exist at runtime, the compiler just *sees* it as `"foo2foo3"` - and all string literals (`"foo1"` and `"foo2foo3"`) are in the pool of strings (from class `String`), that is, are interned - these literals are also in the Constant Pool (even less relevant)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel We not explore the universe because we have to. So why we still doing it?

Comment: That is a false comparison IMO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The strings `"foo1"` and `"foo2foo3"` are values of *compile time constant expressions* and both will be interned.

None of the other strings will be.

- `a` is not interned.
- `a + "foo1"`  is not interned.
- neither `"foo2"` or `"foo3"` is interned.  In fact *runtime* `String` objects are not even created for these 2 literals.  The `"foo2" + "foo3"` expression is evaluated at compile time.

---

The fact that strings are immutable doesn't predict whether a string value is interned or not.  (All strings are immutable, but only some are interned.)

Finally, all of this is irrelevant to *practical* programming.  If you consistently use `equals(...)` to test strings, interning (or not) has no effect on program behavior.

In a modern JVM, the GC's string de-duplication feature is a better way to manage space consumed by possible duplicate strings than interning.  And the amount of memory occupied by literals / constant expressions should be insignificant anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. First time I heard "interned". A new knowledge has been learned.